# How to control alignment of mail header?

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I encounter a situation, when I send a email which email subject more than 80 char, sometimes the email subject will be insert a 'tab' char. I check the invalid email's mail header, they are aligned, if a mail header entry more than 80 char, it will be wrap to a new line, and insert a 'tab'. I don't know which configuration control it, javaMail setting? SMTP setting?

Sample headers:

case one: invaild email subject, inserted a char 'tab'.

```
Received: from as09.aaaaaaaaa.com ([192.168.1.129]) by aaaaaaaaa.com
    ([192.168.1.49]) with ESMTP (TREND IMSS SMTP Service 7.0; TLS:
    TLSv1/SSLv3,168bits,DES-CBC3-SHA) id ba8afe04001a23ba ; Wed, 1 Feb 2012
    16:17:10 +0800
Received: from as09 (localhost [127.0.0.1])by as09.aaaaaaaaa.com
    (8.13.8+Sun/8.13.8) with ESMTP id q118HAgi021891;Wed, 1 Feb 2012 16:17:10
    +0800 (HKT)
Message-ID: <25866052.1328084230581.JavaMail.oracle@as09>
Date: Wed, 1 Feb 2012 08:17:10 +0000
From: <sss@abc.com>
To: ben@abc.com,
    john@abc.com,
    jimmy@abc.com
Subject: test Daily report for city pairs of iPhone App enquiries indocument
     version Demo Customer/Test/Test/123/1231
CC: sam@abc.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

case two: valid email subject, just wrapped

```
Received: from as08.aaaaaaaaa.com ([192.168.1.104]) by aaaaaaaaa.com
 ([192.168.1.49]) with ESMTP (TREND IMSS SMTP Service 7.0; TLS:
 TLSv1/SSLv3,168bits,DES-CBC3-SHA) id c356e969001b37a5 ; Fri, 3 Feb 2012
 09:16:58 +0800
Received: from as08.aaaaaaaaa.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])   by
 as08.aaaaaaaaa.com (8.13.4+Sun/8.13.4) with ESMTP id q131Gw1l006160;   Fri, 3
 Feb 2012 09:16:58 +0800 (HKT)
Message-ID: <17351450.1328231818282.JavaMail.oracle@as08.aaaaaaaaa.com>
Date: Fri, 3 Feb 2012 01:16:58 +0000
From: <sss@abc.com>
To: ben@abc.com
Subject: test Daily report for city pairs of iPhone App enquiries in
 document version Demo Customer/Test/Test/123/1231
CC: sam@abc.com
```

sample java code:

```
public void sendEmail(Request req) throws Exception {
  Session mailSession;
  MimeMessage msg;
  Properties mailSessionProp = new Properties();
  mailSessionProp.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
  mailSessionProp.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

  mailSession = Session.getInstance(mailSessionProp, null);
  msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
  msg.addRecipients("TO", InternetAddress.parse(req.getRecipientAddress()));
  msg.setSubject(MimeUtility.encodeText(req.getSubject(), "UTF-8", "B"));
  msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", "");
  msg.setSentDate(new Date());
  msg.setContent(req.getMessage(), req.getMessageContentType().getType());
  Transport.send(msg);
}
```

JavaMail:

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
    Implementation-Version: 1.3.3_01
    Specification-Title: JavaMail(TM) API Design Specification
    Specification-Version: 1.3
    Extension-Name: javax.mail
    Created-By: 1.3.1 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
    Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.sun
    Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
    Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
    SCCS-ID: @(#)javamail.mf    1.5 02/03/14
```

Comment: JavaMail fold method: [link]http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.java?rev=425

Answer (score 1):

`JavaMail` will wrap the header when you call setSubject(), and unwrap it when you call getSubject().

Comment: But same java code, why sometimes insert 'tab', sometimes not? I checked JavaMail, it just wrap the subject, not insert a new char '\t'.

Comment: You'll need to show me some examples for sometimes/sometimes not.  The way headers are formatted is that wrapped lines (continuation lines) start with a whitespace character.  The MIME spec allows space or tab, but JavaMail chooses tab because it makes the headers easier to read when reading the raw MIME message.

Comment: Hi Bill, I upload some sample mail header. I checked JavaMail code, it doesn't insert tab when it wrap the mail header.

Comment: Show me the details of how you tested this.

Comment: I have two application server, as08, as09(every application server own a smtp server.). I call the send email function on as08, then check mail header, found the mail header folded. Then I call the send email function on as09, check mail header, found the mail header folded and inserted a 'tab'.

Comment: Those aren't really the relevant details.  I don't care what the names of your machines are.  I care about the lines of code that are constructing the message, the lines of code that are reading the message, and the configuration of JavaMail on each machine, including which version(s) you're using.  When you say "send email function", what exactly does that mean?  When you say "check mail header", what exactly does that mean?

Comment: "send email function" means sendEmail method will be call. "check mail header" means I receive the email, and I check the mail header. Could you show me where JavaMail insert the 'tab'?

Comment: You check the mail header by writing a program that uses JavaMail to read the header?  Or you check the mail header by using a mail reader program's "view source" function?  Or by some other method?  It's the MimeUtility.fold() method that does the wrapping, and looking again at the code it's wrapping the line at an existing whitespace character, either a space or a tab.  It's not always inserting a tab.

Comment: I check mail header by using a mail reader program's "view source" function. You can see the case one, all header are aligned, the folded header are inserted a 'tab'.

Comment: I suppose we should back up and ask why you think it's a problem that the wrapped lines have a tab instead of a space, since the spec allows either one?  If you have a program that's reading the mail header and isn't handling the tab properly, your program is broken.  Note also that you can find out exactly what JavaMail is going to send by using msg.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt")).  If that shows spaces, then the message is being changed by your mail server or your mail reader.

Comment: The email subject inserted a tab is deformed when it display in email client(outlook). I think the mail header is changed by mail server, but I don't know which mail server config control it.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is correct according to http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html

> 2.2.3. Long Header Fields
>
> Each header field is logically a single line of characters comprising the field name, the colon, and the field body.  For convenience however, and to deal with the 998/78 character limitations per line, the field body portion of a header field can be split into a multiple
>      line representation; this is called "folding".  The general rule is that wherever this standard allows for folding white space (not simply WSP characters), a CRLF may be inserted before any WSP.

Comment: Hi Tichodroma, do you know which system insert the 'tab'? How to config it?